# Confused about "Clear" command in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I'm currently trying to make a "Clear" command for my discord bot, (!clear **number**) however I'm obviously doing something wrong; I'm pretty new to coding and I hope someone can see where I've gone wrong.

In my main.js file, I have, amongst all the others, this:

```
    } else if(command == 'clear'){
        client.commands.get('clear').execute(message, agrs);
    }
```

and in my clear.js file, I have this code which is probably completely wrong.

```
module.exports= {
    name: 'clear',
    description: 'clears an amount of messages.',
    execute(message, args){
        const args = message.content.split(' ').slice(1);
    const amount = args.join(' ');
    if (!amount) return msg.reply('You haven\'t given an amount of messages which should be deleted!'); 
    
    if (isNaN(amount)) return msg.reply('The amount parameter isn`t a number!'); 
    
    if (amount > 100) return msg.reply('You can`t delete more than 100 messages at once!'); 
    
    if (amount < 1) return msg.reply('You have to delete at least 1 message!'); 
    
    await msg.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: amount }).then(messages => {
        msg.channel.bulkDelete(messages
    )});
    }
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this instead:

```js
// delete `const args = messsage.content...`, args is already defined via command handler
const amount = args[0]

// code...

const fetched = await msg.channel.messages.fetch({
      limit: amount,
    });
    msg.channel
      .bulkDelete(fetched)
      .catch((error) => console.log(`Couldn't clear messages because of ${error}`)
```

Comment: hm... I have removed  'const args = message.content e.c.t,' and replaced it with amount = args e.c.t

In the very last line, it underlines the ending parentheses and says "unterminated template literal" 
Any help?

Comment: Oh, I'm stupid haha. Close the `console.log()` with a backtick (`). I edited my answer accordingly.